# Extracting a Square Root and Cube Root Notation

Tags: mathematics

From *A Synopsis of Elementary Results and Applied Mathematics:*
[image: Part 1]
[image: Part 2]

> **Question:** I am confused on three main parts:
>
> - What is happening in **35**? Why does the author get all of the numbers?
> - Why multiply $3\times 2,3\cdot 2^2, 3\cdot 2^3$ in the second line of the explanation?
> - How would you interpret the notation used?

---

I have spent an ample amount of time on this, and although I can understand * a bit* of finding the cube root, I'm still puzzled on the square root. I'm assuming that they *are* supposed to be similar...

Comment: Might this be better for Mathematics Stack Exchange? I feel like this is just a pure mathematics question.

Comment: @HDE226868 Hm.. they recommended me post the question here...